# Why can't I use "npm start" in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to initialize the `npm start` command on my newly created React app. This is the first time I am doing this, and I have no clue what's happening.

Node version: 12.14.1
npm version: 6.13.4

I've tried to find the solution and I couldn't.

````
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.14.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~prestart: myapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: myapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Gianfranco Vasallo\Desktop\myapp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Gianfranco Vasallo\bin;C:\Users\Gianfranco Vasallo\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.4.0;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin;C:\Users\Gianfranco Vasallo\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Gianfranco Vasallo\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Gianfranco Vasallo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
9 verbose lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Gianfranco Vasallo\Desktop\myapp
10 silly lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle myapp@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid myapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Gianfranco Vasallo\Desktop\myapp
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.14.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error myapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the myapp@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]```
````

Comment: Where's the rest of the output? How was your app set up? Give a [mre].

Comment: I already edited the main post with the output. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: can you try
npm start --verbose

Comment: Have you run npm install?

Comment: what's the script for "start" in your package.json ?

Comment: this looks like the same issue as this (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7736) one.

Comment: My "start" script is this:                                                                               
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }